# There exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^c f(t)dt = \int_c^b f(t)dt$

Tags: integration

If $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is integrable prove that there is $c\in[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^c f(t)dt = \int_c^b f(t)dt$.
I set $g(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ but I don't know how I must continue.

Comment: What the value of $g(x)$ at $x = a$? What's the value of $g(x)$ at $x = b$? What's the value you *want* to have for $g(c)$? You might do better to let $h(x) = \int_a^x f(t) ~dt - \int_x^b f(t) ~dt$ and answer the same questions for $h$, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: This is question 600075 ...

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function in $[a,b]$, we may define a function $F(x)$ such that

$F(x) = \int_a^x f(y)\;dy$

---

$F(x)$ will be continuous in $[a,b]$ and differenciable in $(a,b)$:

$F'(x) = f(x)$

$F(a) = 0 \;\; ; \;\; F(b) = \alpha$

([Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus))

---

By splitting the integrals, the problem becomes: show that $\,\exists \, c\in(a,b)$ such that

$F(c) = F(b) - F(c) \Leftrightarrow F(c) = \frac{1}{2}F(b)$

Since $F(c) \in[0,\alpha]$, the existence of $c$ can be directly proved by the
[Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)